# Sub pixel drawing with opengl

Tags: c++, opengl

I am drawing lots of small black rectangles to the white screen and as they move about and zoom it doesn't look very graceful.

How can I draw them so if the edge lies between pixels, the pixels will be grey rather than black?

Comment: How are you drawing the rectangles?

Answer (score 3):

Sub-pixel rendering is actually more complicated than regular anti-aliasing. If you're using a display with pixels in RGB format, then a gray shape ending halfway through a pixel might be rendered as yellow or as cyan, depending on which side of the pixel the shape lies. This can look strange when the resulting image is not drawn in native resolution or on a display with a different layout than expected, but otherwise it can look quite nice.

[image: Subpixel rendering applied to text]

Here is a sample of sub-pixel rendering applied to text; the left panel is color, the center panel is the displayed version of the color, and the right panel is the perceived brightness. Notice that accuracy in hue is exchanged for accuracy in brightness.

One approach might be to render each channel separately, each slightly offset in rendering space by the appropriate amount, so that the combined image is in full color. Each of the channels must be the same resolution as the resulting image; each channel is rendered with anti-aliasing the same way as the original would have been, except the other colors are ignored. Once the channels are created, they can be combined with simple addition. I don't know of a "pure" solution like the glEnable/glHint versions available for normal anti-aliasing, but it may exist or may in the future.

Answer (score 0):

`glEnable(GL_SMOOTH);` should do it.

Comment: Smooth polygons are not available on all implementations. Also they're tedious to use. Instead I'd recommend multisampling.

Comment: @datenwolf: But we're not talking about arbitrary polygons.  I would expect rectangles to be supported (and can always be drawn as a pair of triangles if necessary).

Comment: Replace "Polygon" with "filled primitives". OpenGL calls it polygon smoothing, but it applies to triangles and quads, too. Smooth mode is tedious to use, anyway.

Comment: @datenwolf: What implementation doesn't support triangle smoothing?  AFAICT this feature has been around for a loooong time, and is not deprecated in 3+, so it ought to be nearly universally available.

Comment: Some (older) implementations simply don't to it (edges remain jagged), some implement it by drawing lines along the edges with jittered endpoints. All in all POLYGON_SMOOTH is evil. Multisamples provide much better quality and are easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

What you are effectively asking for is `anti-aliasing`,and there are numerous ways of doing it.  One way is summarized in this gamedev topic: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/107637-glenablegl_polygon_smooth/.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glHint(GL_POINT_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);
glHint(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);

glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
```

Comment: I tried this and the blocks are still moving a pixel at a time. I tried splitting into two triangles and its still happening